# Installed Java 6 in Downlods folder what should i do now?

Tags: installation, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java 6/7 JRE or JDK?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-6-7-jre-or-jdk)

I am new to Linux and i used instruction specified in Oracle's documentation on how to install Java on Linux. Now when i checked with Java -version i got invalid command message.

After searching in different directories i found java directories in Downloads folder. Please suggest what should i do a new install or any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to software center and search java 7 for the latest version and click install it will install properly.

Sticking to software center or using apt in terminal is the best way to install.

Comment: But i can only see Open JDK 7, what if i want to use Oracle JDK?

Comment: Im no expert in java but a quick Google gives me the impression they are the same thing ? Dont know this as a fact but try it.

Comment: yep Open JDK 7 seems to be perfectly fine, i will be using it as of now. Once i get better with ubuntu i will try Oracle one. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help :)